# When can we decompose a multivariable p-adic power series into product of single variable power series?

Tags: computational-number-theory, power-series, local-rings

Is there any known result of decomposing multivariable power series over $p$-adic field into product of single variable power series ?

For example, consider the following power series in $n$ variables:$$ f(x_1,~x_2, \cdots, x_n)=\sum_{j_1,~j_2,\cdots, j_n=0}^{\infty} a_{j_1,~j_2, \cdots, j_n} \prod_{k=1}^{n} (x_k-c_k)^{j_k}.$$

Now we want to express $f(x_1,~x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ in the following way:
$$ f(x_1,~x_2, \cdots, x_n)=\left(  \sum_{i_1=0}^{\infty} a_{i_1} x_1^{i_1}\right) \cdot \left(  \sum_{i_2=0}^{\infty} a_{i_2} x_2^{i_2}\right) \cdots \left(  \sum_{i_n=0}^{\infty} a_{i_n} x_n^{i_n}\right).$$
When and under which condition is it possible?

Is there any results or notes or resources available in this regard ?

Thanks,

Comment: A necessary condition is given by $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} =  \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f \right) f$$ for all $i \neq j$. My guess is that this is also sufficient (at least in characteristic zero, which you are assuming anyway).

Comment: @RP_, Thank you very much. Yes , I checked for small degrees, your condition comes true. But I didn't see how did you get the necessary condition ? Can you be more explicit about the derivation of the necessary condition ?

Comment: Well, just write $f = f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2) \cdots f_n(x_n)$ and compute both sides of my equation. For simplicity, let $i=1, j=2$. Then both sides are clearly equal to $f'_1(x_1)f_1(x_1)f'_2(x_2)f_2(x_2)f_3(x_3)^2 f_4(x_4)^2 \ldots f_n(x_n)^2$.

Comment: @RP_, Thanks. So it seems that it is also sufficient condition as you said in p-adic case (char $0$).

Comment: Just to be sure: by "necessary condition" I meant that if the power series can be written as a product, then it must satisfy the equation (so if it doesn't satisfy it, it is not a product of $n$ univariate power series). From what I wrote above I can't draw the conclusion that the condition is also sufficient. I have thought about it but I don't see how to prove that it is sufficient. I thought I could maybe prove it but unfortunately I was too optimistic.

Comment: @RP_, I got your point. Thank you for nice effort

Comment: @RP_, can you please look into my another question in mathstackexchange.com ? It is here [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814244/what-are-concept-of-division-of-multidimentional-multi-components-functions)

Comment: @RP_, While I am trying to prove the sufficiency part, I just want to discuss one thing with you. Once we have the decomposition into single variable power series, without loss of generality, we can assume each factor (each single variable power series) in the product has distinct zeros. Second, finite product and direct sum are equivalent. So we can think $f(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n)=\oplus_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x_i)$  instead of $f(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x_i)$ also. Is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some night thoughts on your question which are too long for a comment.  For simplicity, I will look at the two variable case.  Firstly, there is a very simple discrete criterion for when a function of two variable splits in the way you are interested in: Let $f$ be a function from $X \times Y$.  Then is can be represented as a product of two functions of one variable if and only if $$  f(x_1,y_1)f(x_2,y_2)=f(x_1,y_2)f(x_2,y_1) $$ for all possible values of the variables.

This is purely set theoretical situation but one can ask the same question in various contexts (continuous, smooth functions, or power series) and a small additional argument is required to show that if a function splits in the above sense, then the factors automatically have the required smoothness.

With respect to a differential condition, I will cheat and suppose that $f$ is a smooth real-valued function on the plane. (I know nothing about the $p$-adic case but hope that this might give you some pointers).  Then, as above,
$f f_{xy}=f_xf_y$ is a necessary condition for splitting and the question is whether it is sufficient.  This is certainly true (using logarithms) if $f$ has no zeroes.  In cases (like yours) where it can only have isolated zeroes I imagine that one could use a localisation argument to prove the sufficiency but I haven’t examined the details.

Comment: Thank you very much . In the last para 3rd line, what do mean by $\text{as above}$ ? Are you referring the comment by @RP_  ?

Comment: Yes,  indeed I was.

Comment: ok,thank you very much

Comment: I didn't understand the argument how the condition is sufficient using logarithm ? Can you explain it ? Second, using localization we will get new functions, the rational functions or Laurent(type) power series. How this conclude the sufficiency ? Any clue please ?

Comment: If you use the tranformation $g= \ln f$, the differential equation takes on a very simple form.  For the second question, one can use this fact to get a factorisation in a neighbourhood of any point where $f$ is non zero, then piece them together to get one away from the zeroes.  But as I said, I haven’t thought this through so if you want to use this “fact” anywhere you will have to bite the bullet and find out whether it can be solidified to a precise proof.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice help.

Comment: Can you please look into my another question in mathstackexchange.com ? It is here [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814244/what-are-concept-of-division-of-multidimentional-multi-components-functions)

Comment: Sorry—I looked but don’t have the expertise to be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: While I am trying to prove the sufficiency part, I just want to discuss one thing with you. Once we have the decomposition into single variable power series, without loss of generality, we can assume each factor (each single variable power series) in the product has distinct zeros. Second, finite product and direct sum are equivalent. So we can think $f(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n)=\oplus_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x_i)$  instead of $f(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x_i)$ also. Is it ?